# What is GCC's "vstring"?

Tags: c++, gcc

I read some GCC bugreport and people there were talking about "vstring". Searching the WEB I came to notice http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/vstring_8h.html .

Can someone please elaborate on what it is useful and used for? Why use it instead of std::string?

Comment: The link you provided mentions right at the top *"This file is a GNU extension to the Standard C++ Library."* Ofcourse, that does not answer your question completely.

Comment: If memory serves, that is/was an experimental reimplementation of `std::string` with the same interface but different guts.  The file has copyright dates in 2005-2007 and nothing since; recommend searching the [`libstdc++` mailing list archive](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/) in that time period for mentions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GCC's `vstring` is a versatile string class, which was introduced in GCC 4.1's `libstdc++` implementation.

It is compatible with `std::basic_string`, with these additional details:

- Two base classes are provided:

  - the default one avoids reference counting and is optimized for short strings;
  - the alternate one, still uses it (reference counting, that is) while improving in a few low level areas (e.g., alignment). See `vstring_fwd.h` for some useful typedefs.
- Various algorithms have been rewritten (e.g., replace), the code streamlined and simple optimizations added.
- Option 3 of DR 431 is implemented for both available bases, thus improving the support for stateful allocators.

DR431 is [Library Working Group Defect Report 431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#431), with option 3 looking like implementing better allocator support for the class to allow better swapping and other allocator-related operations.

The basic details are from [GCC 4.1's release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.1/changes.html), under the Runtime Library section.

edit:

It looks as though the original purpose of this extension was to provide a basis for a C++11 `std::string` implementation. Paolo Carlini, a GCC/libstdc++ contributor, comments in this [GCC Bug Report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52938#c8) that `<ext/vstring.h>` contains a non-reference counted experimental version of the next `std::string`. Comment dated April 12, 2012:

> What we tried to explain is that this sort of issue is well known and, more or
>   less, affects *any* reference counted implementation...
>   **That is not the case when reference counting is not used and indeed it will *not* be
>   used (per the new C++11 Standard) in a new implementation of `std::string` which
>   we are currently showcasing as `<ext/vstring.h>`**...

Comment: What's the rationale for inventing it? Will it eventually become the implementation of std::string?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - I believe that was the original purpose of `ext/vstring.h`, that it would provide a non-reference counted string implementation that would eventually become the default (or be the basis) of a new `std::string` implementation for GCC's C++11 implementation. There are various comments in GCC mailing lists and bug reports that seem to point toward that, like this comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52938#c5 and this: http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A--RFC--C%2B%2B1x-breaking-the-ABI-in-one-more-place-%3A%28-p28618810.html. That's as much as I know without asking.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-01/msg00064.html implies that the only reason it has not already become the `std::string` implementation is ABI compatibility constraints.

Comment: With the ABI transition in GCC 5 I introduced a new `std::basic_string` implementation, copying most of the code from the SSO versions of vstring.

Comment: For those who don't recognize the acronym (like me up until a few seconds ago) - SSO is the "short string optimization" mentioned above. See also [Meaning of acronym SSO in the context of std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10315041/1593077) here on Stackoverflow.