# How to replace std::string with vstring?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, libstdc++

I recently learned, that since a few years the library libstdc++ contains `vstring` (also known as `versa_string`), which provides the same functionality as `std::string`, but is apparently more conforming to the C++ standard. I have tried to use `vstring` as a replacement for `std::string`, but I have found no easy way to do it.

**Is there an easy way to replace `std::string` with `vstring`, without changing the libstdc++ sources?**

I am fine with replacing all uses of `std::string` within my code by an alias, as indicated by the following listing. However, the problem with this approach is, that `std::string` is also used internally in some places, e.g. in `std::ostringstream`. That means, the statements `std::ostringstream os; my::string s = os.str();` no longer works.

```
namespace my {
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
    using string = __gnu_cxx::__vstring;
#else
    using string = std::string;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Recent version ? `vstring` was added in 4.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463851/what-is-gccs-vstring.

Comment: I seem to remember Herb Sutter saying in some video that gcc4.9 was going to make `std::string` non-ref counted, but I don't see that in the release notes. You can fix the error in the one case you've listed by using `my::string s = os.str().c_str();` instead. There might even be a way to access the underlying streambuf to avoid the intermediate `std::string`, but I'm not sure of that part.

Comment: @Praetorian: JW said it wouldn't make 4.9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431633/does-g-meets-stdstring-c11-requirements#comment32348898_21431742

Comment: Indeed, rumours of the COW string's death have been greatly exaggerated ;-)  To answer the question, no, there is no way to replace `std::string` in the library. You'll have to wait for GCC 4.10

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I think you could make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to replace `std::string` with `vstring`, it's meant as an alternative string type, not a drop-in replacement for `std::string`

Since GCC 5.1 the library ships with two implementations of `std::string` and for any given translation unit you can choose which to use via the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro. The two string types have different mangled names, so are not link-compatible.

See [Dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) for more details.

Comment: Would you mind updating this answer given how GCC has progressed since 2014?