# Is it possible to use C++11 ABI _and_ both cxx11-style and old-style strings?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stdstring, abi

I have some code which is being built with GCC 5.3.1 without _GLIBCXX_CXX11_ABI set. Now, suppose I want to use both old-style and new-style `std::__cxx11::string`'s in the same bit of code . Is that possible? If so, how?

Notes:

- I don't really have a good reason for doing this. I do have a not-so-good reason, but let's make it a theoretical question please.
- It's ok if the C++11 strings aren't called `std::string`.

Comment: ...you want them both called `std::string`?

Comment: @T.C.: Ah. I see your point. Suppose that I'm ok with the C++11 strings not being called std::string.

Comment: `ext/vstring.h` is your friend, then.

Comment: @T.C. Link / explanation?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463851/what-is-gccs-vstring

Comment: c++11 strings are still std::string.  It was an ABI change for GCC, not language standard change. As for your question: try it yourself or dive into ABI changes and report back. Some code works, some not.

Comment: If you have a not-so-good reason, I think you'll have to go deeper, an assembly level/linker hacks etc

Comment: [required reading](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you have both the old and new `string` implementation in the same code? Not exactly. The [Almighty Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/api.html) states:

> ABI transition adds new implementations of several components, using
>   the `abi_tag` attribute and the `__cxx11` inline namespace to
>   distinguish the new entities from the old ones.
>
> - Use of the new or old ABI can be selected **per-translation unit** with the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro.
> - New non-reference-counted string implementation.

Now you could theoretically compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and use `ext/vstring.h`, which was GCC's conforming string implementation before the breaking ABI change. I wouldn't be surprised if things blew up, though.

Comment: Wait, isn't that contradictory? I mean, vstring is the old implementation, and `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` will give me the old implementation as `std::string`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @einpoklum No, copy-on-write is the old string implementation, "non-reference-counted" is the new one (aka `vstring`. What I'm saying is there's no reason to use `vstring` in C++11/the new ABI).