# Different memory address for &string and &string[0]?

Tags: c++, string

From [Strings in Depth](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gregjor/project/eckelbook/volume2/Chap04.htm), I learn that the exact implementation of memory layout for the string class is not defined by the C++ Standard. But how come `&string` and `&string[0]` will have different memory addresses?

```
string variable("String Test");
cout << (void *) &variable << endl;         // 003EFE58
cout << (void *) &variable[0] << endl;      // 003EFE5C
cout << (void *) &variable[1] << endl;      // 003EFE5D
... ...
```

But they do share the same content, check out:

```
cout << ((string)*(&variable))[0] << endl;  // 'S'
cout << *(&variable[0]) << endl;            // 'S'
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: `string` is not an array type, it's a class type. This would work as expected if you declared an array of `char`s.

Comment: @H2CO3 correct, agree, removed confused because of printf

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan **No!** The op asks for `std::string` ...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yeah, not too good practice to use `printf()` in C++ code...

Comment: @H2CO3 How can I print the address of `&variable[1]` in C++ without using printf()?

Comment: @herohuyongtao `std::cout << (void *)&variable[1]`

Comment: Actually, that isn't right.. http://ideone.com/Qw91Gt  and  http://ideone.com/7saE8R

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Actually, I am right, and you don't know the difference between an **array** and a **pointer.** In your code, `str` is not an array, it's a pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks, updated the question by removing `printf`.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames And while we are throwing IDEOne links at each other's face (which is meaningless, a particular compiler cannot possibly be regarded as a C++ reference implementation): http://ideone.com/eDTKDs

Comment: Guess that is one of those flaws of having arrays and pointers being use interchangeably. `operator []` on a pointer and `operator []` on an array results in the same thing which is what confused me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because one is the address of the class instance, the other is the address of the first character, which is typically contained in dynamically-allocated memory managed by the class (or somewhere in the instance itself in the case of [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring)).

Answer (score 2):

String is an object. It has some fields in its beginning. This is implementation specific. In your case there is just one 4 bytes field. The sting that it contains starts with an offset. In fact, the sting can be in a heap buffer. It may not be in the object itself.

Comment: It's not that "it has some fields in its beginning". The array is typically dynamically allocated, so there's really just a pointer to some other (completely unrelated) block of memory.

Comment: True. This is what goes on in 99% of cases. Should I distrust the listing in the original post? Maybe the reasons are still needed.

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, who knows what a modern optimizing compiler with `std::string` intrinsics might do with a string instance constructed from a string literal. (e. g. turning it into a struct which contains an auto array instead of a dynamically allocated pointer...)

Comment: Then why you disprove my statement in your comment?

Comment: Because this is not the **typical** and **straightforward** reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to confuse a lot of programmers, so I will do my best to explain it.

```
// here, you take the address (&) of the first item in the variable array...
//       you then convert that address to a string object
//       an implicit cast occure, which constructs a string instance and copies the contents of 
//       the referenced item in variable (which is a dereferenced char* char('S'))
//       this line is similar to:
//         char c = *(&variable[0]); // dereference
//         string S = string(c);     // copy
//         printf("%c\n", S);        // print
printf("%c\n", ((string)*(&variable))[0]);  // 'S'

// here, you do the same dereference of the first item in variable,
//       except you don't copy it into a string object
//       similar to
//         char c = *(&variable[0]);
//         printf("%c\n", c);
printf("%c\n", *(&variable[0]));            // 'S'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the first one, it's `((string)*(&variable))[0]` not `((string)*(&variable[0]))`.