# For a guaranteed single character, is it better to use `char` or `string`?

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a variable that's guaranteed to be a single character (substr from a `std::string`).

I strongly suspect that it's more efficient to use a `char`, i.e.

`char c = name.c_str()[offset];`

instead of the more complicated (and costly)

`std::string c = name.substr(offset, 1);`

I'm not going to do any intensive operations on the resulting character (just one `switch` statement).

Comment: You can just do `char c = name[offset];` in that first example.

Comment: depends on your definition of "character" if you are talking about single byte, you'll be fine. If you are talking about single unicode character in UTF-8 string, then you won't.

Comment: You could just switch on `name[offset]` if you wanted to.

Comment: If you want to do a `switch()` statement then you have to use a `char` because you can't use `switch()` with `std::string`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace unless offset is allowed to indicate the null terminator

Comment: To make this decision you would take into account what you're doing with it later. Using `char` to store a single character makes the most sense, in a vacuum.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, noted. I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation. @Galik, if I used a `std::string` then I would have used a `if-else` chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to use a `char` in this case, assuming you want to store it and process it often latter, otherwise you can just directly access the `string` individual `char`s using `operator[]`. One thing to note is that `std::string` implements the so-called [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10315041/3093378), which should be quite fast. But anyway, **you should profile your code**, and unless you need a `std::string` (e.g. to be passed around latter in some other functions), you should just use a `char`.