# Cannot see local variables values

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

When debugging with WinDbg I cannot see value of local `std::string` variables. I can see values of boolean variables but when hovering over a string variable or viewing it in Locals window, all I see is the type of the variable but not its actual value.

How can I see the value of a local `std::string` variable?

Answer (score 6):

Despite being simple on the outside, `std::string` is a surprisingly complex type and WinDbg just doesn't have the smarts to display it in a more human-readable format.

Hovering over it in WinDbg shows something like this:

[image: Tooltip in WinDbg of std::string]

And, that's not helpful at all.

Luckily, the data is there, we just have to dig for it. In our case, the `string`'s value is hiding in the `_Bx` member. We can get to it by running `dt -r3 myString`. This will recursively print the members of `myString` to the console (up to 3 levels).

```
0:000> dt -r3 myString
Local var @ 0x23fd90 Type std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
   +0x000 _Myproxy         : 0x00445638 std::_Container_proxy
      +0x000 _Mycont          : 0x0023fd90 std::_Container_base12
         +0x000 _Myproxy         : 0x00445638 std::_Container_proxy
            +0x000 _Mycont          : 0x0023fd90 std::_Container_base12
            +0x004 _Myfirstiter     : (null) 
      +0x004 _Myfirstiter     : (null) 
   +0x004 _Bx              : std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> >::_Bxty
      +0x000 _Buf             : [16]  "test1234"
      +0x000 _Ptr             : 0x74736574  "--- memory read error at address 0x74736574 ---"
      +0x000 _Alias           : [16]  "test1234"
   +0x014 _Mysize          : 8
   +0x018 _Myres           : 0xf
   =00a00000 npos             : 0x905a4d
```

It took some work, but we got there.

---

Some things to keep in mind:

1. Understand that you are looking under the hood of the implementation of a library type. This can (and will) change at any time. The implementation in my screenshots is from VS2015 and will likely differ from other versions.
2. The string's value is tucked away in the `_Bx` union as a means to implement the [Small String Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) (SSO). When the string is short enough, it will be stored in `_Bx._Buf`, otherwise, it will be allocated on the free store and a pointer to it stored in `_Bx._Ptr`. Don't be shocked if you see what looks like garbage data in one of them, but valid data in the other.
3. This isn't a problem in Visual Studio's debugger because they have ways of visualizing types and data structures. This is done with [.NATVIS files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgoldin/archive/2012/06/06/visual-studio-2012-and-debugger-natvis-files-what-can-i-do-with-them.aspx) which are provided by Visual Studio for common types like `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

paste this line in a txt file and use $$>a< to execute the script 
this will dump all the Local std::string->c_str() whose length are > 16

```
!for_each_local ".printf \" @#Local = %ma\\n\" , poi( @#Local )"
```

for strings that are shorter than 16 use `da <name>`

[image]

Comment: You said: "the script this will dump all the Local std::string->c_str()", but the script does not distinguish between strings and other locals, so any other type of local variable might generate incorrect output, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes as there is no universal correct method and the internal structures of std::string often are not same across vs versions (see the display by sean cline where there is a container Myproxy and the Bx is at 0x+4 not at 0x0 which the script assumes will also provide errenous result but it works in most of the case and when there is an error you get a type not fuund , foo is not a member of blah etc which will provide a direction to take)

Answer (score 0):

Try the "View Locals" icon or ALT+3, it should show at least the address.

Comment: I think OP already uses the locals window since he/she said "viewing it in Locals window".