# Calculating pi using Monte Carlo method in two ways in C++ OpenMP

Tags: c++, algorithm, openmp, montecarlo

What method should be faster?
First method is increment one variable for reduction:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(seed, x, y, i) reduction (+:counter)
{
    seed = 25234 + 17 * omp_get_thread_num();
    nproc = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<prec/8; i++){
        x = (double)rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX;
                y = (double)rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX;
        if(x*x+y*y<1){
            counter++;
        } 

}
```

And the second one is using table of increment variables per process and at the end, sum of elements in this table is a result:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(seed, x, y, i , nproc)
{
    seed = 25234 + 17 * omp_get_thread_num();
    nproc = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<prec/8; i++){
        x = (double)rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX;
        if(x*x+y*y<1){
            counter[nproc]++;
        } 

    }
}

double time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    sum+=counter[i];

}
```

Theoretically, the second way should be faster, because processes are not sharing one variable, but every process has own variable.
But when I calculate time of execution:

```
first approach: 3.72423 [s]

second approach: 8.94479[s]
```

Am I think wrong or am I do something wrong in my code?

Comment: `reduction` variables **are** private, which invalidates your argument.

Comment: I don't think this should be a duplicate the question is not the same even if the answer has the same conclusion. [exemple here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) (surely not the best)

Comment: @coincoin, while it is not word-for-word the same question, the core premises are the same. Of course, anyone on SO is free to disagree and vote for reopening of the question.

Comment: @HristoIliev I don't really mind personnally it's fine ! Just by curiosity how can we vote for reopening the question ? I can't see that I guess I there is a minimum amount of points to have right ?

Comment: @coincoin, I really meant _almost_ anyone. You need 3000 points to be able to access the close/reopen voting - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are victim of [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) in the second approach. Here an interesting [article from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads) about that.

> False sharing occurs when threads on different processors modify
>   variables that reside on the same cache line. This invalidates the
>   cache line and forces a memory update to maintain cache coherency.
>
> If two processors operate on independent data in the same memory
>   address region storable in a single line, the cache coherency
>   mechanisms in the system may force the whole line across the bus or
>   interconnect with every data write, forcing memory stalls in addition
>   to wasting system bandwidth

Intuitively, I don't think the first approach should be slower.
You indeed create a private copy on each thread and then apply the final result in a global variable. The behaviour is somehow the same with your shared array, but the problem here is even if your accesses are independent, you get false sharing.