# Disable std:string's SSO

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I wonder if there is a way to programmatically disable string [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) to make it not use local buffer for short strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As SSO is an optional optimization, there won't be a standard way to turn it off.

In practice, you can just `reserve` a string that won't fit into the SSO buffer to force the buffer being allocated dynamically:

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(sizeof(str) + 1);
```

That seems to work for gcc at least and should even work portably as the internal buffer needs to fit inside the string. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3a4f9a46b0008d1))

Comment: Any known downside of using this approach?

Comment: @SayantanGhosh The obvious one is that by disabling the optimization, you lose its performance benefits. The more interesting question here is: What would be the upside of doing this? If your code doesn't work with SSO, but does without, you'd be better off fixing your code than tinkering with the symptoms.

Comment: I was facing this same issue with set emplace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896539/stdvectorstdwstring-is-moving-reallocating-inner-wstring-data-legal  Was evaluating manual allocation using a char array vs the above for this since the allocation brings in some set of additional management on free up.

Comment: @BaummitAugen one example is storing string views (or raw pointers) into a string. Usually this is perfectly valid with move semantics, but when the string uses sso it'll fail. Quite annoying to be honest.