# C++ - A better way to create a null terminated c-style string of specific size with same character

Tags: c++, string, fill

I am looking to create a null terminated `c-style string` where every character is `-` (hyphen). I am using the following block of code:

```
char output_str[n + 1];
std::fill(output_str, output_str + n, '-');
output_str[n + 1] = '\0';
```

1) Is there a smarter **C++ way** to do this?

2) When I print the size of the string the output is `n`, not `n + 1`. Am I doing anything wrong or is null character never counted?

**Edit:**

Please consider this block of code instead of the one above:

```
char output_str[n + 1];
std::fill(output_str, output_str + n, '-');
output_str[n] = '\0';
```

And please ignore the question regarding size.

Comment: `output_str[n + 1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: VLA's aren't standard c++. Make sure `n` is a `constexpr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a smarter C++ way to do this?

Sure, use a `std::string` to do that:

```
std::string s(n,'-');
const char* cstyle = s.c_str();
```

Comment: As a bonus, some (but not all) implementations use the [Small String Optimization / SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) which means this code may store all of its data on the stack (for small enough values of `n`) just like the code in your question does!

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there a smarter C++ way to do this?

Using the String class:

```
std::string output_str(n,'-');
```

In case you need a string in old C style

```
output_str.c_str(); // Returns a const char*
```

> 2) When I print the size of the string the output is n, not n + 1. Am I doing anything wrong or is null character never counted?

In your code, the N caracter is not added. If the array was pre-filled with zero, strlen function will return N.

Comment: Just curious, what is old C?

Comment: @mvds using char* for strings

Comment: @amchacon That didn't change for _newer c standards_ yet.