# Returning const char* from a string literal in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-literals, const-char

Normally, I would return a `std::string` from a function because returning a `const char*` would require the caller to provide an output memory buffer, and that buffer is not resizable.

But is returning a `const char*` valid if its from a string literal?

```
const char* generate_c_string() {
    return "ABC";
}
```

Doing in this way (if valid) would likely be faster as I would not need to dynamically allocate memory to construct a `std::string`.

It probably is valid, because `const char* x = "ABC";` is valid.  Is there a reference from the C++ standard that substantiates its validity?

Comment: I don’t understand why the caller would require to provide any buffer if you return a pointer.

Comment: Despite voting to close as a duplicate, I upvoted question and answer because both are still useful

Comment: Note that for such short strings the most common std::string implementations do not allocate any dynamic memory. [Meaning of the acronym SSO in the context of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring)

Comment: It's quite possible that a `std::string_view` suffices if you don't need a full `std::string`. Of course it still has the same lifetime requirements since it doesn't use its own storage.

Comment: @Sami If the function wasn't as simple as returning a static string (perhaps we need to concatenate some text), then the caller should pass a output `char*` argument to the function.

Comment: Oh, yes, as an argument, but then one wouldn’t return a pointer. That’s what baffled me.

Comment: @Sami Sorry, I wasn't clear about that in the question. But wouldn't I still need to return a pointer to the past-the-end character?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is valid, for [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal),

> String literals have [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

The pointer returned would remain valid in the life of the program.

Comment: Does this cover borderline scenarios such as `generate_c_string` being imported from a dynamic library that later gets unloaded?

Comment: @VTT That sounds worthy of a question