# Using const char* as key for map/unordered_map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

How to create map/unordered_map that will use `const char*` as key directly?

If I use `map<std::string,..>`, then on each resolving `map["abc"] = ...` a new `std::string` object will be created. That causes a big overhead for allocating memory, creating a string object and copying the string into it.

How do I declare a map object that uses `const char*` directly without any overhead?

Comment: Before you complain about "overhead", *test it*, and *benchmark it*, and *profile it*. And no you can't really use pointers of any kind as the key, as then it will be the *pointer* that is the key and not what it points to.

Comment: That is not going to work as the default specializations for `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` will fail to behave like you'd expect.

Comment: How long are the key strings? How many different ones do you expect? Are the keys variable or a fixed set? What is the lifetime of the keys?

Comment: with string key finding element take 70 nanoseconds, but with long long key it take 20 nanoseconds.  With const char* I'm expecting result close to long long. Any way with std::string memory allocation may occur that unacceptable.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

```
std::map<std::string_view, int> Map;
Map["abc"] = 1; // no allocation necessary to store "abc"
```

It is basically a wrapper around string objects. And it's a view, which means that it doesn't own the string and thus doesn't copy and allocate memory to store a string.

Note that for small strings (and also literals), `std::string` doesn't allocate too due to [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319672/2477364) and so the overhead is minimal. Always measure before optimizing.

Comment: And if you don't have C++17 you can use [`absl::string_view`](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/strings) (in fact you can use it in both cases, since it will be `typedef`'d to `std::string_view` if it exists).

Comment: @jdehesa Or [`boost::string_view`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp) :)

Comment: std::string_view may be good feature but unfortunately it's will come in new standard and not present in my compiler vc++12  now((

Comment: Upgrade to vc15 or vc17. You'll be glad you did. Seriously.

Comment: @nik As others have said, there's `boost::string_view` then.

Comment: --Upgrade to vc15 or vc17.
I can't do that because vc14 is the latest version  ))

Comment: This is brilliant, and faintly terrifying. Think of the abuse and subsequent UB we'll get in sane-looking programs :/

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to [Rakete1111's `string_view` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50608442/1782465), you can equip your map with a suitable comparator (and hasher, for the `unordered_map`):

```
struct LesserString
{
  bool operator() (const char *lhs, const char *rhs) const
  {
    return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
  }
};

struct HashString
{
  std::size_t operator() (const char *arg) const
  {
    return however_you_want_to_hash_the_string();
  }
};

struct EqualString
{
  bool operator() (const char *lhs, const char *rhs) const
  {
    return !strcmp(lhs, rhs);
  }
};

std::map<const char*, WhateverValue, LesserString> m1;
std::unorderd_map<const char*, WhateverValue, HashString, EqualString> m2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will use pointer as map keys it will compare keys based on pointer addresses, the same keys will be treated as different. So you will have to create your own comparison function when dealing with plain pointers, so you will better use some wrapper on plain pointers like other answer suggested.