# New array allocation with flexible size struct?

Tags: c++

I'm reading about struct with flexible array members and I wrote a little program to test my understanding:

```
struct HelloWorld {
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

std::string arr[5] = { "abcdetttttttttttttttttttttttttt", 
                       "abcdefgh", "abcrrrr", "abcdtttttttt",
                       "abcdezzzzzzzz" };
HelloWorld * h = new HelloWorld[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << (h+i) << std::endl;
    h[i].a = 5;
    h[i].b = arr[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  std::cout << (h + i) << std::endl;
}
```

First of all, I read that the flexible array member, in this case the string b, is not counted toward the size of the struct when using sizeof. However, when I calculate sizeof HelloWorld it returns 48 bytes. Shouldn't it be just 4 bytes? Secondly, When I dynamically allocate an array of 5 HelloWorld, each object's adress is separated by 48 bytes. Even when I fill the member b with different-sized string, these addresses dont change, so I'm guessing the struct is storing the strings somewhere else and not in the allocated space by "new". Where are these strings being stored?

Comment: "flexible array member" is a C thing. It doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: Why do you think `std::string b` is a flexible array member?

Comment: `std::string b;` is just a single `string`. It's not an array.

Comment: hit pause, rewind and play again. Maybe from a better source, a better book. You started on a wrong path to learn C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver so a string is size is the same no matter how long the string is? I dont understand

Comment: I feel obliged to mention that you should get [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)

Comment: `sizeof()` is a compile time constant.

Comment: [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a class which stores (possibly) dynamically allocated character data. It is NOT an array.

Comment: ***However, when I calculate sizeof HelloWorld it returns 48 bytes. Shouldn't it be just 4 bytes?*** No `std::string` has a fixed size. It should be larger than 4 itself.

Comment: Yes, `sizeof(std::string)` is always the same.  `std::string` allocates the memory it needs dynamically so it only stores a pointer to it (actually more but we really don't need to get into that yet).

Comment: ***Even when I fill the member b with different-sized string, these addresses dont change, so I'm guessing the struct is storing the strings somewhere else and not in the allocated space by "new".*** std::string will allocate memory for the string when it needs to do so. It will use new to do this.

Comment: Let me add that you should forget _everything_ you know about C. At one time, C++ could be considered a superset of C, but this is no longer so.

Comment: C and C++ : *Very* different languages.

Comment: `sizeof(string)` is not 0, so `sizeof(HelloWorld)` can't be 4 (assuming `sizeof(int)=4`). At a *minimum*, a `string` must be `sizeof(void*)` if it stores ALL its data in dynamic memory (rare). Typically the size is closer to `sizeof(char*)+sizeof(size_type*2)` as the `size` and `capacity` are stored in the `string` itself` while the `char*` points at the payload elsewhere in memory. Modern libraries use [Small String Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/) to store small payloads directly in the `string` itself (which is why `sizeof(string)` is so large in your case).

Comment: @RobK It's still approximately true.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are mixing up the two different languages C and C++, and you are trying out the concept of flexible array members available in C within the language C++, where this concept does not exist at all.

A brief example of flexible array members in C, taken from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct), yet shortened a bit:

> If a struct defines at least one named member, it is allowed to
>   additionally declare its last member with incomplete array type...
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; }; // s.d is a flexible array member 
> struct s *s1 = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + 64); // as if d was double d[8]
> s1->d[0] = 1.0;
> s1->d[1] = 2.0;
> ```

So with a flexible array member, you can individually create smaller or larger `struct s`-objects as you like while still being able to use the notation `s.d[x]` to access the members of that array.

In language C++, in contrast, a definition like `struct s { int n; double d[]; }` is illegal as C++ simply does not support flexible array members.
In C++, you will solve such issues by using a dynamic collection data type as member:

```
struct s {
   int n;
   std::vector<double> d;
} s1;
...
s1.d.push_back(1.0);
s1.d.push_back(2.0);
s1.d[0] += 10;
```