# Memory allocation for struct that has a STL class c++

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I'm running tests to see how variables are getting placed on the memory and sizing them out when I use a struct.
Consider I have a struct that looks like below:

```
typedef struct _ttmp
{
    WCHAR wcsTest1[13];
    WCHAR wcsTest2[13];
    wstring wstr;
}TTMP, *LPTTMP;
```

How big is the size of `TTMP` when STL classes like `wstring` are dynamically allocated?

Am I treating `wstr` as a 4-byte pointer?

I ran some tests to see the size of `TTMP` and got the size of the struct to be `88-bytes`
and two of `WCHAR` arrays were `26-bytes` which leaves the size of wstr to be `36-bytes`, but that `36-bytes` does not really make sense if I were to treat the wstring as a pointer. Seems like alignment padding does not apply here since I'm only using 32-bit variables.

Also, would it be bad a practice to use `ZeroMemory` api on structs with STL?
I've heard from someone that it is not safe to use the api, but the program ran fine when I test it

Comment: `ZeroMemory` is ok for POD types but you never know how non-POD stuff manages its fields so the closest safe C++ equivalent to it is probably `std::uninitialized_value_construct_n` from C++17.

Comment: *but the program ran fine when I test it* -- Change the code.  You're invoking undefined behavior by using `ZeroMemory` on such a `struct`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(WCHAR[13])=26`, which is not an even multiple of 4 or 8, so alignment padding *would* account for a few bytes (unless you set the struct's alignment to 1-2 bytes via `#pragma pack(1)` or `#pragma pack(2)` or equivalent).

But, `std::(w)string` is much more than just a single pointer. It may have a few pointers in it, or at least a pointer and a couple of integers, which it uses to determine its `c_str()`/`data()`, `size()` and `capacity()` values.  And it may even have an internal fixed buffer for use in [Small String Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319672/1805388), which avoids dynamic memory allocation of small string values (this is likely true in your situation).  So, at a minimum, a `std::(w)string` instance could be as few as, say, 8 bytes, or it could be as many as, say, 40 bytes, depending on its internal implementation.

See [Exploring `std::string`](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/std-string/) for more details.

In your case, `sizeof(std::wstring)` is likely 32 (that is what gcc uses, for instance).  So, `88-26-26-32=4`, and those 4 bytes could easily be accounted for by alignment padding.

And yes, `ZeroMemory()` would be very bad (ie, *undefined behavior*) to use on a struct containing non-POD members.