# What does "in-situ without memory allocation" mean for folly implementation of String?

Tags: c++, string, folly

From Folly documentation

```
Small strings (<= 23 chars) are stored in-situ without memory allocation.
Medium strings (24 - 255 chars) are stored in malloc-allocated memory and copied eagerly.
Large strings (> 255 chars) are stored in malloc-allocated memory and copied lazily.
```

**Where are these "Small String" stored ?**

Comment: Can't say for certain, but most likely they mean they use the guts of the object itself, like a union of a actual string members and a char array, and they use the char array until the string grows and then switches to use the string members and allocating.

Comment: Sounds like Folly's version of the Small String Optimization (aka SSO):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/10319672#10319672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the cost of `std::string` already includes 23 characters. Anything more requires additional allocations.

This means internally the structure looks approximately like:

```
struct string {
  // ...
  char internal[23];
  char* external;
};
```

This is presumably to make copying short strings very cheap as no heap operations have to be performed, plus it doesn't require any `delete` calls to clear.