# std::wstring::find() broken in g++?

Tags: c++, g++, valgrind, wstring

What's wrong with this program:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::wstring s = L"12345";
    s.find(L"x");
    return 0;
}
```

If nothing is wrong, why does Valgrind complain:

```
$ g++ -g main.cpp 
$ valgrind ./a.out 
==9301== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9301== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9301== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9301== Command: ./a.out
==9301== 
==9301== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9301==    at 0x54AD3C1: __wmemchr_sse2 (memchr.S:254)
==9301==    by 0x4F7667A: std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::find(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==9301==    by 0x108A28: main (main.cpp:5)
==9301== 
==9301== 
==9301== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9301==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9301==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 72,728 bytes allocated
==9301== 
==9301== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9301== 
==9301== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9301== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==9301== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Note that when I reduce the size of the string by one character:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::wstring s = L"1234"; // string is shorter by one character
    s.find(L"x");
    return 0;
}
```

or when I search for a character that is in the string:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::wstring s = L"12345";
    s.find(L"5"); // '5' is in the string
    return 0;
}
```

or when I use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring`:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s = "12345"; // std::string instead of std::wstring
    s.find("x");
    return 0;
}
```

then Valgrind does not complain.

My environment:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dave-VirtualBox 4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 10:07:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ valgrind --version 
valgrind-3.13.0
```

Comment: *Note that when I reduce the size of the string by one character:* -- Shortening the number of characters will probably invoke the Short-String-Optimization of the `string` class, thus no memory would be allocated.  [Here is more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/10319672#10319672)

Comment: I tested with g++ 10.2 and valgrind 3.16,. it did not show the error. So probably due to bug either on older version of g++ or valgrind.

Comment: @Jaebum Thanks for the hints. I built Valgrind 3.16.1 on my Ubuntu 18. That version of Valgrind reports no error. Could you post your message as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bug on valgrind side. I tested with g++ 10.2 and with valgrind 3.16, it worked without an error.

Comment: I built Valgrind 3.16.1 on my Ubuntu 18. That version of Valgrind reports no error (g++ version unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

Not really a bug, but the old Valgrind version probably doesn't know about sse string operations.

As an optimization, str* and mem* functions can do 8 byte reads in the knowledge that memory will always be allocated in 8 byte increments. So this may read beyond the end of the string but it will never read unallocated memory.