# Why is it not possible to compare the output of .what() method of thrown exception with a string?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, string-comparison

The code fails to print `True` because the comparison fails for some reason. I don't know what it's, but it works if I change `e.what() == "Something Bad happened here"` to `e.what() == std::string("Something Bad happened here")`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    try
    {

        throw std::runtime_error("Something Bad happened here");

    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        if(e.what() == "Something Bad happened here") {
            std::cout << "True" << "\n";
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `what()` returns `const char*`, you are comparing two pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`std::exception::what()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) returns a `const char*`, and a `"string literal"` is a `const char[N]`. Operator `==` on them does a comparison of two pointers. You must use `strcmp()` on them

```
if (strcmp(e.what(), "Something Bad happened here") == 0) // ...
```

`std::string` OTOH has an `operator==` to [compare with a `const char*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)

---

If you have C++14 then you can get a `std::string` without an explicit constructor with the [`s` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
if (e.what() == "Something Bad happened here"s) // ...
```

But of course a `std::string` is still needed to be constructed before comparing, which may be a little bit slower than `strcmp` when [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10315041/995714) doesn't kick in

---

In C++17 there's [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) which needs pretty much zero cost to construct from a string literal, so you can use this

```
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;
if (e.what() == "Something Bad happened here"sv) // ...
```

Comment: In C++17: `std::string_view(e.what()) == "foo"` or `e.what() == "foo"sv`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes I did look at `std::string_view` but I misread it so I thought you can't do `==` on `std::string_view` and `const char*`