# Memory allocation in the C++ standard library

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Recently, I became interested in tracking memory allocation and deallocation. When overloading the new and delete operators, I found that the C++ standard library sometimes calls the overloaded operators and sometimes allocates memory using other methods. (Probably `std::allocator`.) For instance, `std::string` seems not to use `new`. Although, `std::vector` seems to call `new` when `push_back` is called. This is surprising since I would think the standard library would have a uniform policy to manage memory allocation.

When does the standard library choose to `new` vs `std::allocator`? Why?

Comment: What makes you think that `std::string` doesn’t (indirectly) call `new`? What makes you think that `std::allocator` doesn’t use `new`, or that `std::vector` doesn’t use `std::allocator`? Are you aware of the [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring)?

Comment: First of all, you should publish your code you used for testing. For example, we must be sure that std::string wasn't allocated on stack (heap is not used) or no copy was created.

Comment: AFAIK, `std::allocator` allocates memory with `operator new` as well. Anyway, as already noted, you are likely a victim of SSO. This means that `std::string` does not need to allocate memory for short strings up to some limit (usually 15 or 22 characters on a 64-bit architecture).

Comment: `std::allocator` (the templated allocator that standard containers use by default) use `::operator new(size_t)` or (since C++17) `::operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)`.   It is unspecified when or how that function is called (which allows the containers and allocators to tailor strategies for how they allocate and manage memory).

Comment: Yes, I was forcing the copy constructor to be called during testing. SSO was preventing the operator from being called. Thanks @Sneftel.

Comment: The reason `std::allocator` was introduced was old times when x86 processor had two types of pointers near and far. This might be helpful: https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard containers will use the allocator provided to them to allocate dynamic memory. By default, that is `std::allocator`.

For most other dynamic memory uses in the standard library, the standard doesn't specify how the implementation should acquire memory, and the implementation has the freedom to do what they want.

---

As for tracking memory allocations, I recommend wrapping `malloc`.