# C++ pointers in class costruction

Tags: c++, class, pointers, visual-c++, boost

I'm trying to solve this problem from several days.

In this program there is an `unordered_map` which from string key to structure value. The idea works, but when I put the `unordered_map` in a class and then access it more easily I get an error:

```
Eliminare.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<std::string,Data,std::_Uhash_compare<std::string,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>>,boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<std::string,Data>,boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char,boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void,__int64,unsigned __int64,0>,0>,boost::interprocess::iset_index>>,0>>::_Find_last<std::string>(const std::string & _Keyval, const unsigned __int64 _Hashval) Row 1510    C++
    Eliminare.exe!std::unordered_map<std::string,Data,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>,boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<std::string,Data>,boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char,boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void,__int64,unsigned __int64,0>,0>,boost::interprocess::iset_index>>>::at(const std::string & _Keyval) Riga 387    C++
Eliminare.exe!MapCreator::getValue(std::string Key) Row 37  C++
Eliminare.exe!main() Row 7  C++
```

This is the main:

```
#include "MapCreator.h"

int main() {
    MapCreator mappaClass;

    auto values = mappaClass.getValue("value");
}
```

While this is in MapCreator.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include<iostream>
typedef struct Data
{
    int a;
    int b;
}dataClass;

namespace bost = boost::interprocess;
typedef std::string    KeyType;
typedef dataClass MappedType;
typedef std::pair<std::string, dataClass> ValueType;
typedef bost::allocator<ValueType, bost::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef std::unordered_map<KeyType, MappedType, std::hash<KeyType>, std::equal_to<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MySHMMap;

class MapCreator
{
public:
    MySHMMap* mappa = nullptr;
    MapCreator() {
        bost::shared_memory_object::remove(nameMemory);
        bost::managed_shared_memory segment(bost::create_only, nameMemory, sizeDeclared);
        ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());

        mappa = segment.construct<MySHMMap>("MySHMMapName")(alloc_inst);
        dataClass value;
        value.a = 12;
        value.b = 1111;
        mappa->insert(std::pair<std::string, dataClass>("value", value));
        std::cout << mappa->at("value").a;

    }
    dataClass getValue(std::string Key) {
        return mappa->at(Key);
    }
private:
    const int sizeDeclared = 65536;
    const char nameMemory[20] = "SharedMemoryName";
};
```

The "`cout`" in the `MapCreator` constructor correctly prints "12", but using the `getValue` function, it prints the error mentioned above.

Thanks for your help, if you have any questions about the code, just ask.

**INFO:**

- Compiler: Visual C++ with Visual Studio 2022
- the code without the class works well
- the version of boost class is: 1.78.0

Comment: "*in this program there is an unordered_map that goes into a shared memory to access it in another process*" - that will never work.  You can't share containers across process boundaries, you can only share fundamental types.  Containers typically contain pointers to data, and those pointers are only valid in the process that allocates the memory they point at. Processes don't share memory address spaces. *Maybe* if you used a custom allocator that allocated shared memory... but even that is risky and uncertain to work.  So, just don't do it.

Comment: Pointers cannot be shared across processes.  If you're picking up any STL structure that uses pointers or allocates memory, it won't work.

Comment: But i already tried the code and it works really well, but when i tried to create the class and make the code cleaner, it seems to lose the pointer. the question therefore is NOT the sharing between the processes, but why that error comes out in this code

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought it was possible but you had to use custom allocators.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, look the code, i use it. but the error is another. the error is not between processes but in the main process that generate the map

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have a zillion examples of much more complicated containers - including unordered_map  - in shared memory. It *can* work with the right allocators.

Comment: @sehe so do you know what is my error? just copy all code in visual studio And it reproduces the problem

Comment: I do. Was already writing the answer.

Comment: It's taking a while, but then you'll have something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

The first one is that `segment` is a local variable in your constructor, meaning that `mappa` is a dangling pointer after the constructor returns.

Second, bigger, problem is that your map uses a shared memory allocator correctly, but the strings do NOT. String are also dynamically allocating, so your solution cannot work unless you make the string also use shared memory.

Starting the fix:

```
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc  = boost::container;
using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Mgr>;
using MyString   = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using KeyType    = MyString;
using MappedType = dataClass;
using ValueType  = std::pair<KeyType const, MappedType>;
using MySHMMap   = std::unordered_map<KeyType, MappedType, std::hash<MyString>,
                                    std::equal_to<MyString>, Alloc<ValueType>>;
```

> *Note that on my compiler it's also required to use `KeyType const` in the `ValueType`.*

In the execution there's additional complexity: `segment` must be a field, but it can only be constructed from the initializer list (or using [NSMI](https://www.cppstories.com/2015/02/non-static-data-members-initialization/)). That means that we have to make the `remove` also occur (before that) in the initializer list. Here's my initial attempt:

```
template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Mgr>;
using MyString   = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using KeyType    = MyString;
using MappedType = dataClass;
using ValueType  = std::pair<KeyType const, MappedType>;
using MySHMMap = boost::unordered_map<KeyType, MappedType, boost::hash<MyString>,
                         std::equal_to<MyString>, Alloc<ValueType>>;

class MapCreator {
  public:
    MapCreator()
        : mappa(segment.find_or_construct<MySHMMap>("MySHMMapName")(
              segment.get_segment_manager()))
    {
        mappa->emplace(MyString("value", segment.get_segment_manager()),
                       dataClass{12, 1111});
    }

    dataClass getValue(std::string key) const {
        return mappa->at(MyString(key.c_str(), segment.get_segment_manager()));
    }

  private:
    static constexpr int sizeDeclared = 65536;

    // note: declaration order defines initialization order!
    std::string_view nameMemory = "SharedMemoryName";

    struct pre_remover {
        pre_remover(const char* name)
        {
            bip::shared_memory_object::remove(name);
        }
    } pre_remove{nameMemory.data()};

    Segment segment{bip::create_only, nameMemory.data(), sizeDeclared};
    MySHMMap* mappa = nullptr;
};
```

> Notes
>
> - there was also no reason at all to allocate a fixed size buffer of 20 chars for the name.
> - The order in which members are declared is the order in which they're initalized. That's important because `mappa` needs to come after `segment`, e.g.

I found out that `std::hash` isn't actually specialized for the `MyString` instance, and because I know down the line I'd want to change that anyways I'm not wasting time to create a Hash function object. Instead, I'm switching to `boost::unordered_map` just so `boost::hash<>` is used

This is already working **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27566ce579b0bb7a)**

Prints:

```
12, 1111
```

### Improvements

1. Scoped Allocators

   Things are pretty clunky around the allocator/get_segment_manager(). Using scoped-allocators you can alleviate that:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   using Alloc      = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;
   using MyString   = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
   using KeyType    = MyString;

   template <typename K, typename V, typename H = boost::hash<K>,
             typename Eq = std::equal_to<K>>
   using SHMap = boost::unordered_map<K, V, H, Eq, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;

   using MySHMMap = SHMap<MyString, Data>;
   ```

   Now you can "simply" write:

   ```
   mappa->emplace("value", Data{12, 1111});
   ```

   Instead of the complicated version before. **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8f8aea8755d9d6a)**
2. Heterogenous Key Lookup

   The other place where we are constructing `MyString` (just to throw it away after the `at()` call...), we can use `boost::unordered_map`'s *compatible-key lookup*:

   ```
   Data getValue(std::string_view key) const {
       auto it = mappa->find(key, mappa->hash_function(), mappa->key_eq());
       return it != mappa->end() ? it->second
                                 : throw std::range_error("getValue");
   }
   ```

   This requires the hash and equality to be compatible:

   ```
   using MySHMMap = SHMap<MyString, Data, std::hash<std::string_view>,
                          std::equal_to<std::string_view>>;
   ```

   See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ff87ab9f4638fbb)**
3. Using C++20 standard unordered_map instead (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find):

   ```
   struct Hash : std::hash<std::string_view> {
       using is_transparent = std::true_type;
   };
   struct Eq : std::equal_to<std::string_view> {
       using is_transparent = std::true_type;
   };
   using MySHMMap = SHMap<MyString, Data, Hash, Eq>;
   ```

   And then:

   ```
       Data getValue(std::string_view key) const {
   #ifdef __cpp_lib_generic_unordered_lookup
           auto it = mappa->find(key);
   #else
           auto it = mappa->find(
               MyString(key.data(), key.size(), segment.get_segment_manager()));

   #endif
           return it != mappa->end() ? it->second
                                     : throw std::range_error("getValue");
       }
   ```

   See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02f9a039fc09ecac)** as well

Comment: Posting improvements in a minute

Comment: Posted the improvements I had in mind.

Comment: Just for completeness the first version running on MSVC: https://rextester.com/UTSE85033

Comment: Using scoped_allocators is a lot harder on MSVC - maybe in part due the older versions but here is a start https://rextester.com/KVLT7093

Comment: omg... you are the best... Not only for having solved the problem, but also for the optimization tips you gave me. You've been really professional and kind, now works a wonder :)

What I don't understand, however, is, I realized that strings need a pointer, but why could I read the data correctly in the second process? Perhaps because he trifed him in hash and therefore he no longer needed an allocator?

Comment: Some implementations do [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring):Small String Optimization. That means that Small Enough Strings™ won't require dynamic allocations. Your "it was hashed" hypothesis can't explain it because hash-tables *always* have a two-step lookup: first the fast O(1) hash lookup, then a (typically linear) check using the key-equality comparer, which requires access to the full key data.

Comment: perfect, thx for your help again ;) have a nice day

Comment: oh no! T.T I discovered that actually managed_shared_memory uses a file and not the ram ... do you think it is possible to take it to RAM without distorting the code?

Comment: Managed shared memory uses memory.

Comment: Ah is fine, because every time you start the program and create shared memory, the use of my disk rises, and looking on the net I discovered that he uses the disk. But then I noticed that in reading the data does not use the disc so everything ok.