# Why is the address different?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, stdstring

I wrote the below code for my understanding of pointers.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a = "hello";
    const char *st = &a[0];
    printf("%p\n", &st[0]);
    printf("%p\n", &(a[0]));
    printf("%c\n", *st);
    printf("%p", &a);
}
```

This is the output that I get

```
0x1265028
0x1265028
h
0x7ffe26a91c40
```

If my understanding is correct `&a` should return the address of string, why is the value returned by `&a` different than the rest ?

Comment: Assuming that is `std::string` then you are taking the address of the object - which is not the same as the address of the memory it manages

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `std::string` is a C++ object, which internally holds a pointer to an array of `char`s.

In your code, `st` is a pointer to the first char in that internal array, while `&a` is a pointer to the C++ object.  They are different things, and therefore the pointer values are also different.

Comment: For plus 8 you might want to rephrase "which internally holds a pointer to an array of chars." to cover the short string optimisation possibility.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think SSO is a private implementation detail that doesn't change the the externally-visible behavior of the string nor the validity of the answer as given... but if someone wants to read about SSO, here's a link that discusses it better than I can here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/10319672#10319672

Comment: It's just that is doesn't *always* hold a pointer to an array of chars. Personally I think it's important to be precise, or vague (something like "internally can hold a pointer to...") in your case. Else readers start believing in absolutes.

Comment: I'd say that even when SSO in is use, the `std::string` has a pointer to an array of chars; it's just that it's deriving that pointer from its this-pointer when necessary, rather than keeping it as a separate member-variable.  But this is all very "inside baseball" and probably more confusing than helpful to someone who is just learning C++.

Answer (score 6):

`&a` is the address of the variable `a` of type `std::string`. Since `std::string` contains a character array of variable length, it must use dynamic allocation and store the real array somewhere else.

However, `std::string` has many operator overloads. `a[0]` returns a reference to the first character in `a`'s array, and `&a[0]` is the address of that character. That's why `&st[0]` and `&a[0]` would be the same address, as `st` also points to the first character in `a`'s array.

Answer (score 4):

0x1265028 - address of first char
0x1265028 - address of first char
h - first char value
0x7ffe26a91c40 - address of std::string object

Comment: Love the name. (Also great insight for 1st year student - ping me when you're looking for a job or perhaps need something for the summer.)

Comment: @Bathsheba I graduated over 3 years ago :D