# How can I concatenate the elements of a vector of integers to a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, type-conversion, integer

I've been trying to put every single element of a vector of integers into a string. I want to achieve this by type casting the integers into strings, after that I cocatenate those "small strings" into a single big string, which is going to represent all the elements of that specific vector.

This may look silly, but is really useful if you want to make a function that returns a vector like-a-thing, or etc.

The only problem is that I'm getting an error on line 13, which says :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(int&)’
   13 |     myString += (string) myVector[i];
      |                                    ^
```

and I don't have the slightest idea on why this is happening. My code follows below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int myVector[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

  string myString = "";

  for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    myString += (string) myVector[i];
    myString += "\n";
  }

  cout << myString << endl;
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator), and [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). And if you just going to print the values, then skip the string stream and use `std::cout` directly.

Comment: And as a general hint: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do in attempting to convert the integer to a string) you should see that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: *and I don't have the slightest idea on why this is happening* -- Is it that you are used to other languages that do this type of conversion of integer to string, where all you need to do is have a `+`, and magically the integer will turn into a string?  If so, you see that C++ doesn't work that way.

Comment: in general finding all possible conversions is not easy, finding that there is no conversion is even harder, but a good place to start is looking at constructors of `std::string` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert an `int` to a `std::string`.

Change this line:

```
myString += (string) myVector[i];
```

To:

```
myString += std::to_string(myVector[i]);
```

**Note:** concatenating strings like that might not be so efficient due to temporary strings being created and destroyed (although it is likely that [small strings optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) will kick in, so no additional heap allocations will take place).
As @Someprogrammerdude commented, you can consider to use `std::ostringstream`.

**Side notes:**

1. You are missing `#include <string>`.
2. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: *many temporary strings being created and destroyed* - Due to [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) no heap allocations are likely to occur.

Comment: @Evg clarified that point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::stringstream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    int myVector[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::string myString;

    std::stringstream sstream;
    for (auto i : myVector)
        sstream << i;

    sstream >> myString;
    std::cout << myString;
}
```

[Link](https://godbolt.org/z/xdoq1zEPe).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fmt` library:

1. `fmt::join` will accept a range, in your case a vector of ints, and join its contents with a given separator (e.g. an empty string if you just want all of the elements together).
2. `fmt::format` will create a string with a given format, in this case just the contents of the joined vector.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7rzPTo9a3)

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
  int myVector[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  auto myString = fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(myVector, ""));
  fmt::print("{}\n", myString);
}

// Outputs: 12345
```

Or, simpler, if you don't need the string:

```cpp
int main() {
  int myVector[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  fmt::print("{}\n", fmt::join(myVector, ""));
}
```

---

The error you are getting is saying that the compiler cannot find a `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(int&)` function, i.e., a `std::string` constructor accepting an `int&`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add my own solution, as laid out in my comment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector myvector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::copy(std::begin(myvector), std::end(myvector),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overload the output stream operator, and then you have something reusable for a lot of scenarios.

Based on the feedback below overloading is not the best answer, another approach here : https://www.onlinegdb.com/zDUjVbSTp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// Overloading operator<< will have many benefits.
// you can use it to output an array to std::cout directly
// or you can write it to a file or stringstream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    os << "[";
    bool comma = false;
    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        if (comma) os << ", ";
        os << value;
        comma = true;
    }
    os << "]";

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 1,2,3,4,5 }; 

    // write directly to std::cout
    std::cout << "direct : " << values << "\n";

    // adding array to a string
    std::ostringstream os;
    std::string string{ "output = " };
    os << values;
    string += os.str();
    std::cout << string << "\n";
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would not overload operators for standard types. Suppose you use a library that also provides such overload, and another one that does the same...

Comment: That's a fair comment

Comment: Overloading `operator<<` makes sense for types for which you have more or less canonical output format, like integers or strings. For types like `std::vector<T>` it's questionable because no canonical output exists - one might want to use spaces or commas as separators, to put or not to put the whole sequence into brackets, etc.

Comment: fwiw, a named function `void print(std::ostream& out,const std::vector<int>&)` has the same advantages you list.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes I realize that now too :) https://onlinegdb.com/zDUjVbSTp

Comment: I will leave this answer as it is, since I think it contains good info for others as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **for_each** algorithm as well to do the concatenation.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  

    std::string all;
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&, del=""](const int &e) { 
        all += std::to_string(e) + (&e == &v.back() ? "" : del); 
    });
    std::cout << all << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
123456
```

If you want to add a delimiter in between, just change the `del` value in lambda capture.

```cpp
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&, del="-"](const int &e) { 
        all += std::to_string(e) + (&e == &v.back() ? "" : del); 
    });
```

Output:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6
```