# assign a string with r-value ref constructor still cause memory copy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a = "abcdef";
    cout << (const int*)a.c_str() << endl;//0x64fe20
    string_view av{ a };
    cout << av << endl;//abcdef

    string b = std::move(a);
    cout << (const int*)b.c_str() << endl;//0x64fdf0
    cout << av << endl;// bcdef
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x64fe20
abcdef
0x64fdf0
 bcdef
```

All the point of `b = std::move(a)` is to avoid copy.

We can see the string_view is  `bcdef` and since the entire string is on b, so the string is must be copied (at least part of it), right?

And we can see the inner string buffer a.c_str() and b.c_str() are different. Ok, you can see C++ doesn't guarantee the buffer is same, but how to implement it without copying?

I tested on both VS2022 and GCC(I forget the version) with C++20 standard.

Comment: .c_str() might also not be doing what it thinks you are doing. From [std::string::c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) : `Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.` (it is not required to return the internal data of the string, it can/will return a copy with an extra null terminator)

Comment: Try with a longer string and google "short string optimization".

Comment: Just accept that there's a optimization happending for strings that are short enough. (Storing the data as part of the object itself instead of a dynamically allocated string.) If a dynamic allocation did happen, the ownership of the memory would be transferred by the move operation.

Comment: The second `cout << av << endl;` is undefined behavior. You get "\0bcdef" just lucky.

Comment: @Nelfeal, I guessed so, haha!

Comment: @Nelfeal Consider posting as answer.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Too lazy to elaborate. If anything, I'd mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring. I didn't because the question is quite different, even it answers OP's question.

Comment: @Nelfeal, I tried a much longer string, you are right, the c_str()s became same!

Comment: @PepijnKramer I believe that's not true in C++11 or later. The same page says `c_str() and data() perform the same function.`, and the page for [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) says it `returns a pointer to the underlying array serving as character storage`. I also found [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/string.accessors#1).