# Programme crashes while deallocating a character array

Tags: c++

When I run the .exe being created with the below code in debug mode , it shows some assertion failure and the programme crashes But when i run the same exe created from the release mode of the below code , its working fine.

Please help to identify why I am geting the assertion failure in debug mode but not in release mode .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char *buf  = new char[5];   //pre-allocated buffer
    buf = "Hello";
    delete [] buf;
    getchar();
    //cout<<buf;
    //string *p = new (buf) string("hi");  //placement new
    //string *q = new string("hi");  //ordinary heap allocation
}
```

Comment: Note, in this case, you could say `char buf[] = "Hello";`, and you'd get a copy you wouldn't even have to deallocate.

Comment: You rarely need C strings in C++, you should use `<string>` instead. In the few cases where you actually need C headers, you should use the C++ ones instead (e.g.: <cstring>).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 char *buf  = new char[5];   //pre-allocated buffer
```

Here you define a pointer, and initialize it to point to a dynamically allocated buffer with room for 5 characters.

```
buf = "Hello";
```

Here you initialize the pointer to point to the beginning of a string literal.

```
 delete [] buf;
```

Here you delete[] the buf pointer, but the buf pointer no longer points to anything you new[]'d up, it points to the string literal. You can only delete/delete[] a pointer that points to something you got from new/new[]. So you get undefined behavior, and likely crash

You likely meant to copy the content of your string into the buffer you new[]'d. Remember to account for the nul terminator:

```
int main()
{
    char *buf  = new char[6];   //pre-allocated buffer
    strcpy(buf, "Hello");
    delete [] buf;
    getchar();
    //cout<<buf;
    //string *p = new (buf) string("hi");  //placement new
    //string *q = new string("hi");  //ordinary heap allocation
}
```

Though, in C++, you'd rather use std::string from `#include <string>`;

```
std::string = "Hello";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I got the concept now .But why the programme does not crash if it runs in release mode .

Comment: @viku Hard to tell. When your code does something that's undefined, pretty much anything can happen. It could crash, it could trash your memory, it could appear to work etc.

Answer (score 4):

1. `void main` is wrong. `main` returns `int`. No exceptions.
2. You're doing `delete[] "Hello"`. `"Hello"` is a string literal; you can't `delete` it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I got the concept now .But why the programme does not crash if it runs in release mode

Comment: @viku It's undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
buf = "Hello";
```

You're basically changing the pointer value (memory address) at which `buf` points to a read-only memory area, because `"Hello"` is a string literal and therefore is stored in read-only memory.

Then you attempt to free that memory, hence the crash.

Also, `"Hello"` is 6-bytes long, not 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
 char *buf  = new char[6];   //pre-allocated buffer
 strncpy(buf, "hello", 6);
 delete [] buf;
```

buf = "hello"; would change the buf's value, from a pointer to new char[6] To a pointer point to "hello", a block of memory not in heap.

Comment: 1. It pretends to be a string function when it has nothing to do with strings.  2. It abstracts behavior that shouldn't be abstracted in the first place.  Issues 1+2 lead to people using it inappropriately (because there is no appropriate use for it). E.g. in the code above buf[5] was originally left uninitialized.

Comment: @melpomene: I'll somewhat agree it doesn't do anything that couldn't have been done by `memcpy` or `memmove` plus `memset`.  (Biggest difference being, it zero-pads the destination to the size you pass in; hence the `memset`.)  In its defense, though, it was meant as (and is) just a safer version of `strcpy`.  I'd argue that naked char arrays should never have been given special status as strings at all; a string should be a `char*` *and* a length, or an array should be able to know its size.

Comment: It was not meant as a safer version of `strcpy`. It is not a safer version of `strcpy`. It is not a string function at all.

Comment: @melpomene: You're being overly dramatic. There are a few select cases where C strings are conceivable in C++.

Comment: What do you mean by "conceivable"?

Comment: @healer: *"not on the heap"* doesn't mean read-only memory, it could also mean stack-allocated.

Comment: I mean delete op can only release memory allocated in heap, but "hello" is not. My English is ...you know...

Comment: @melpomene: Appropriate. Per example, C strings are POD types, `std::string` isn't. You can find a few select cases here: [Why use c strings in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109317/why-use-c-strings-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

Because undefined behavior means anything can happen. The problem is that `buf = "Hello"` assigns the address of a string literal to `buf`, then tries to delete that literal. When compiled in debug mode the checking code sees that the address can't be deleted; in release mode that check isn't done, and the delete just stomps on something that isn't critical.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to deallocate the character-string literal `"Hello"`. This line:

```
buf = "Hello";
```

redirects the **pointer** `buf` to point at the literal `"Hello"`. You probably meant to do this:

```
char *buf = new char[6]; //need one extra space for terminating NUL character
strcpy(buf, "Hello");
```